# How to use oracle numeric functions to categorize values in column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table **Employee** with 2 columns as **Emp_Name** and **Emp_Salary**. I want to retrieve **Emp_Name** and a new column as **Indicator** where it generate  1 for **Emp_Salary** values are greater than 10000, else generate -1.

Can anyone please tell me the SQL Query for this in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either you CASE in your query or IFF. Both will work for you. Below are the code for both clause

```
Select Emp_Name, Emp_Salary, Case when Emp_Salary > 10000 then 1 else -1 end as Indicator 
from Employee
```

or

```
Select Emp_Name, Emp_Salary IIF (Emp_Salary > 10000 then 1 else -1) as Indicator
from Employee
```

Answer (score 4):

A CASE clause should be able to do that:

```
select emp_name, 
       case  when emp_salary > 10000 then 1 else -1 end salary_flag
from employee
```

Comment: This is the first answer and it uses correct standard SQL syntax, so that seem worthy of an upvote.